# Synchronization between worker threads of an ExecutorService

Tags: android, multithreading, cordova, executorservice, cordova-plugins

Does the fact that an ExecutorService stores tasks in a blocking queue create a happens-before relationship between the completion of one task and the subsequent start of another task?

My reason for asking is that I've been tasked with writing a Cordova plugin for Android.  Cordova plugins have a method called `execute(...)` that is overridden to perform different actions.  Apparently, the plugin is instantiated once, and then `execute(...)` is called repeatedly in a worker thread of an `ExecutorService`.  If my understanding of how Cordova plugins work is correct, then I wonder if I have to synchronize `execute(...)`'s access to the plugin state.

**Edit:** My understanding of how Cordova plugins work was incorrect, so my reason for asking this question has been invalidated.  But I'll leave it up out of curiosity.  (Cordova plugins are constructed, and `execute(...)` is called, in a thread named `JavaBridge`... apparently always the same thread, though this is not documented.)

Answer (score 1):

No, the tasks being stored in a BlockingQueue does not guarantee thread safe execution of the worker threads. The ExecutorService interface and it's implementation provide a framework that abstracts the creation of individual threads. The number of worker threads spawned by the executor depends on the pool size configured.

Once a worker thread is spawned, it goes about doing it's work normally. If it gains access and tries to modify an object that is currently being modified by another worker thread, then undefined behavior will happen. It is left up to you to ensure that the modification happens in a synchronized manner. An example of this can be found in the PhotoManager.java class in the sample app available at http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html (intended as a multi threading example for Android developers).

The BlockingQueue is a queue that holds the tasks. The term 'Blocking' refers to the manner in which elements are inserted and removed from the queue. As such, it does not provide any guarantees about the actions taken by the tasks that it holds.

Comment: I just realized that my question was really vague.  I'm not interested in objects that are *currently* being modified by another thread.  Edited for clarity.